# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression with np.zeroes

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, whitelist

I am working on a whitelist project as part of a training course. My program is split into three sections: a whitelist, the user's input, and a third array that counts the instances that a whitelist word appears in the users input. All three sections have been converted into arrays. For example, if my whitearray contains the words (good, talented, special) and my user inputs ("My best friend is a really good flute player. My good friend Celia isn't as skillful."), I should be able to print a result:   good 2

My code:

```
import numpy
whitefile = open('whitefile.txt', 'r')
check = raw_input("Hi! Please enter a string and we will see which words are in the whitefile! Enter here: ")
elementA = 0
check = check.lower()
loopEr = 0
whiteList = []
for line in whitefile:
        myTokens  = line.split( )
        whiteList.append(myTokens)

inpList = check.split()


whiteArray = numpy.array(whiteList).astype(numpy)
#numpy.reshape(inpArray, (2,3))

inpArray = numpy.array(inpList).astype(numpy)

lenwhitefile = len(whiteList)
whiteListCounter = numpy.zeroes((1, lenwhitefile).dtype = numpy.float64)

for i in range(0, len(inpList)-1):
        if inpArray[i] in whiteArray:
                while i in range(0, lenwhiteList):
                        if inpArray[i] == whiteArray[loopEr]:
```

Error Received:

```
File "whitelist.py", line 21
whiteListCounter = numpy.zeroes((1, lenwhitefile).dtype = numpy.float64)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 issues:

1. `zeros` instead of `zeroes`
2. `,dtype` rather than `.dtype`

`whiteListCounter = numpy.zeros((1, lenwhitefile), dtype = numpy.float64)`